# The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

Please kindly navigate to [Can PSTricks or others draw the 4 common tangent lines of 2 “disjoint” circles without having to do extra calculations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7199/2099) and see what happened there.

[image: Image Error]

I am not sure it is a bug but I chose bug tag.

---

### This issue still exists in the following questions

1. [Tikz: using external images as building blocks.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks)
2. [Length between nested lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20654/length-between-nested-lists/20659#20659)
3. [LaTeX Math Jokes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/latex-math-jokes/18360#18360)

Comment: You shouldn't crosspost like this. The SO admins do skim through TeX.SX as well frequently.

Comment: Still affects some material, e.g. in the example in the accepted answer to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10/syntax-highlighting today, and presumably will continue to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just change

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh5Gf.png

to

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjHvG.png

We have a network level "pro" account, so images shouldn't be disappearing, and they should be in both places actually.

Comment: + 1: Ok. Thanks for solving.

Comment: @xport it is odd, we will look into it

Comment: @Jeff: Yes. It is odd. I noticed some links without `stack` still work but only those two did not work. Thank you.

Comment: @Jeff: If this is a the case for more picture, could you rename the URLs automatically for all posts?

Comment: @Martin It is happening for more pictures. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10244/how-can-the-damage-reduction-from-armor-in-league-of-legends-not-have-diminishing/10246#10246

Comment: @Jeff: I noticed that the issue still exists in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/tikz-using-external-images-as-building-blocks.

Comment: @xport,Jeff: Indeed, both http://i.imgur.com/1n9Q1.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/1n9Q1.png don't work.

Comment: @xport in that case, that was actual data loss from the provider a while ago. Hopefully isolated.

Comment: @Jeff: With access to the DB is should be possible to find all image references and check if they still exists, e.g. using a HEAD HTTP request. Then a (hopefully short) list of broken images could be posted to inform the authors to reupload them.

Comment: @Martin, @Jeff: Please also see my answer.

Comment: @Jeff: Would it be possible to implement #2 of [How do we repair Gonzalo Medina's posts containing images?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1440) without bumping about 100 questions?

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution to your example posts #2 and #3. What made me think is that it's both answers by Gonzalo Medina. What happened is this: Up until now, Gonzalo didn't use the "add image" link in the answer form, but he used the imgur homepage http://imgur.com/. (See the soon to be deleted conversation [in the comments here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20654/length-between-nested-lists/20659#20659)).

Before you think "oh no, all his images are lost now": They aren't lost (yet), it just happened that all the imgur links with `i.imgur.com` were [automatically changed to `i.stack.imgur.com`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734). (And all the images uploaded via the "add image" button were copied to that domain.) So if you remove `stack.` from those links, you see that the images are still there.

I only wonder what the best course of action is here, taking into account that Gonzalo has *lots* of answers that would have to be checked. See [How do we repair Gonzalo Medina's posts containing images?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1440)

Comment: +1 @Hendrik: Gonzalo has 5 questions and 355 answers in total. Checking one item a day will be finished in about a year. :-)

Comment: @xport: Then it's too late! The images can be lost after only 6 months. See also my new meta question.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't happen.
AFAIK stackoverflow/stackexchange has a special imgur account which has no time limit on the images.
Normally the images must be viewed at least once every six month, [according to the imgur FAQ](https://imgur.com/faq#long).

Maybe these images where uploaded using a different imgur account by the users themselves? If not then some of the SO admins should have a look on it.

Anyway, it should be best if the OP of these answers could reupload the images using the default imgur interface of TeX.SX.