# How do we repair Gonzalo Medina's posts containing images?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, images

As I explained in [this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/the-image-you-are-requesting-does-not-exist-or-is-no-longer-available/1439#1439), all the links to images that were *not* uploaded via the "add image" button are broken. (EDIT: See also [this announcement by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95732/images-manually-uploaded-to-imgur-are-not-displaying/95734#95734) for the background.) This has the consequence that *lots* of the posts of Gonzalo Medina show this

[image]

instead of the intended image. At the moment I see two possible ways to fix this, one even worse than the other:

1. Manually remove `stack.` from all the image links in Gonzalo's posts. This would bump all the posts; moreover, it wouldn't move the images to the `stack` account, so they would be lost sooner or later.
2. Manually remove `stack.` from the image links and re-upload all the images via the "add image" button. This would also bump all the posts, and it would be even more work.

So what can be done about it?

Comment: This sounds like one for an automated fix: awkward, but I guess doable by the 'powers that be'.

Comment: @Joseph: You're right, that would be the best thing. Just doing it automatically for all of Gonzalo's (old) posts would help a lot, I think. I'll try and draw Jeff's attention here ...

Comment: I really hope there's some automatic way to fix this problem. In the worst case, I could start re-uploading the images using the "add image" button. I'll check this question to time to time to see if there's some (hopefully good) news.

Comment: @Gonzalo: From Jeff's answer it seems that re-uploading them manually is the only option. If you decide to do that, do it slowly and start from your oldest posts (since those images will be lost most early).

Comment: Anyway both points sound like a good way to get the [Copy Editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor) badge :-) (Don't worry, I already have it.)

Comment: @Gonzalo: [A list of all your questions with images](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/q/103964/).

Comment: @Caramdir: One has to point out that this is all the images _up to the date where the recent data dump was created_. Do you know when this was?

Comment: @Hendrik: Good point. It was June 6 (I thought it was just a few days ago, but they seem to announce it quite a while after they actually take the snapshot).

Comment: @Caramdir: Ah, good to know. I notified Martin about your list; see the comments to Jeff's answer.

Comment: @Hendrik: well, I'll start re-uploading images today. Thank you very much for all your interest in this. @Caramdir: thanks for the list.

Comment: Arghhhh! After my first five edits re-uploading I received this message "You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow." This is gonna take for ever. @Martin Scharrer: is there a way to momentarily lift the restriction on the number of daily edits?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Martin has no powers to lift that restriction; you'd have to ask Jeff. However, I think it's better to do it slowly in order to not flood the front page. 5 a day will indeed be very slow, but more than 10 a day would be already too much in my opinion.

Comment: @Hendrik: I see. I agree that flooding the front page is not a good idea. Well, I've already bothered you all so much... I will take it easy and edit 5 posts every day.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Sounds like a good plan. A tip (kudos to lockstep): Open the 5 posts you want to repair in 5 different browser tabs, repair each post and _don't submit_ the edit yet (but put already your text "re-upload image" into the Edit Summary); then in the end submit your 5 edits in quick succession. This has the advantage that the posts will have the same timestamp and are grouped together, and people will know this is your daily image thingy. Thanks a lot for taking this into consideration!

Comment: @Hendrik: nice tip. Will do it that way. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gonzalo: You're welcome. And don't be afraid because of bothering anyone - you didn't do that intentionally, after all. I just hope it doesn't bother _you_ too much doing all this re-uploading for several weeks.

Comment: @Gonzalo: My method would get it done in one go without bumping edits.  Jeff's said he'd do his part so that might be the easiest for you.

Comment: @Andrew: Oh, he did? That's great. (Do you have secret communication channels? Like e-mail?)

Comment: @Hendrik: err, no.  He posted a comment below my answer.  My reading was that he was okay to do his part, do you have a different reading?

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, this post is already so long that I didn't see that comment. I only looked below your "Would my solution be feasible" comment and found nothing. So sorry for the confusion. I read it the same way you do.

Comment: Another user affected seems to be [Dave Jarvis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2148/dave-jarvis).

Comment: @Martin: I don't think anyone except me will find your comment `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: I know. I was thinking editing your question or add it as an answer, but then thought I push the black-peter to you ;-) I notified him already and he might not want to be mentioned all too publicly.

Comment: @Hendrik[Jun24,14:06]: I just applied your method. It worked when I edited three posts at once, but the second time (five posts at once), it failed, even though the edits were submitted within three seconds: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ9t1.png. Any idea what might've gone wrong? Was three seconds too slow?

Comment: @doncherry: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that they don't have _exactly_ the same timestamp? It's close enough for people to see that you did some housekeeping since the 5 posts are grouped together and are edited within the same minute - good job!

Comment: @Hendrik: Never mind, I misunderstood the comment I referred to. I thought you meant that not all edits would appear in the news feed if I submitted them in quick succession. I saw just now that you were pointing at the grouping effect. However, when I edited three posts at 16:02:16, 17 and 18 today, only two of them made it in the news feed, so there might be some magic. To be precise, my edit to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14576/typeset-a-series-of-characters-with-equal-distances/14584#14584 wasn't bumped. When I edited a batch of five a bit later though, all of them were bumped.

Comment: @doncherry: Ah - lockstep edited that one, too, _because_ it was bumped. (This bumping is _very much_ by design, almost no exceptions.) By the way, doing 5 at once is OK in my opinion, but do it only once a day then. _Maybe_ twice, but that's already 10 old questions bumped. (OK, you thought that wouldn't happen.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've gone through the [list](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/q/103964/) Caramdir provided and couldn't find any more broken images. I've been reuploading the images in batches of five for the past month or so (= solution 2 of the OP), and it looks like they're all fixed now. Dave Jarvis doesn't have as many posts and just a few still needed fixing. So unless there are more users who have been sneaking around the official uploading-interface, **this issue can be regarded solved**.

Comment: I've noticed you doing this and just wanted to say "Thank you" for taking the time and effort.  I also thought that the "5 at a time" worked: it was enough that it was clear that there was some "housekeeping" going on, but not so many that it flooded the front page.

Comment: I've also noticed that you were doing this. All I can say is "Thanks a million!". I really appreciate what you've done!

Comment: Fixed [morbusg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1410/morbusg)'s posts as well, just a few were concerned.

Answer (score 9):

Hmm. I could easily replace the URLs on all his posts, but that sweeps one very important issue under the rug:

> Unless you [purchase a $24.95/yr imgur pro account plan](https://imgur.com/register/upgrade), images you upload to imgur may be *lost forever* any time after 6 months.

That is, we NEED images to uploaded through the built-in image button here, because those images are guaranteed to stay around forever per our contract with imgur.

These images need to be re-uploaded under our network account, and I don't have a magic tool which does that.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks a lot for looking into this. I agree: Even if you _can_ do #1 from my question in one go, it won't really help. It's a pity that you can't do #2 with some magic tool!

Comment: Hm now I see why my suggestion won't work at all. Thanks for the clarification, Jeff!

Comment: @Hendrik, @Jeff: If there would be a list of all image URL in all of Gonzalo's posts I might be able to write a script to download and re-upload them while noting the new URL. Then a mapping table OLDURL->NEWURL can be created which could be used in a DB search&replace command/script. OK, sounds not trivial either, so I would understand if you SX people don't want to do it.

Comment: @Martin: Caramdir made a query for all the posts containing images up to June 6; see the comments to the question.

Comment: @Hendrik: Nice! I was thinking to create a SQL query myself. It would be even handier if the image URL would be listed instead of the post titles and IDs.

Comment: @Jeff: thanks for your answer. @Martin Scharrer: Thank you and don't bother yourself writing the script. I'll start today the re-uploading process; don't waste your time because of my mistake.

Comment: @Jeff: More precisely: "How long do you keep the images?
As long as images are getting at least 1 view every 6 months, they will stick around forever. After that, your image may be removed to create more space for newer images. " (Source: [imgur.com FAQ](http://imgur.com/faq#long))

Comment: @Martin: That goes beyond my SQL skills.

Comment: @Caramdir: Beyond mine too. I was planning to look through the online SQL references to see if there is some command to extract and return text.

Comment: @Jeff: Would my solution (see my answer to this question) be feasible?

Comment: Correction (which Martin already gave above, but I missed it, so I quote other page), quoting http://imgur.com/register/upgrade: _Normal images that are not viewed for 6 months may be removed. However, images with pro accounts can only be removed by you._ So in practice it's a problem only for users who do not constantly view their all images at least once a few months (which is a good practice for many reasons). :-)

Comment: @prz that is the official policy, but we have seen images get removed that *should* have had a view in the last 6 months. So I would regard that as a loose guideline only, and all low-view images are risk after 6 months.

Comment: @Jeff: It is pretty bad if imgur really treats own guidelines that loosely. I can only hope that what you've seen (actually not seen) was before they changed this guideline to current wording. Truth to be told, it may be changed again in future (e.g. for worse), so sticking to imgur SX is surely the best possible option.

Answer (score 5):

One way to avoid the edit bumps would be the following, though it would need some action by Jeff (or another overlord).  Gonzalo could upload all of the images to imgur in one go by posting a "question" here on meta which included all of the images added via the correct method. Then armed with a list of the old urls and the new ones, Jeff could replace all instances of the old ones with the new ones reasonably simply.  That would get it all done in one go and would mean that no answers were bumped to the front page.

Comment: Sounds like a very good idea! Will you ask Jeff if he'd do the last step?

Comment: sure, tedious, but there's no other way here that I can see

Comment: @Jeff.  Thanks.  I've drawn it to Gonzalo's attention to see if he'll go for it.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. Just to have everything clear (for myself): I would post a question on meta in which I would include all the images, but this time using the "add image" button. I would also have to include two lists: one with the old URLs and another one with the new ones. Is that *all* that I have to do?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4):

I was thinking on a possible solution for this issue. But since we are part of the StackOverflow framework, this idea would certainly affect the whole structure.

Considering [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) about getting rid of salutations, we could come up with a similar RegEx pattern to automatically fix the image links. At least, here in TeX.SE. Not sure it can be done locally, though. The benefits i see from this approach:

- We don't need to do anything. Posts are fixed by themselves.
- Every single image that matches the pattern will be automatically fixed, not only Gonzalo's.
- We can prevent old, current an future image issues by simply adapting the pattern rules.

Anyway, those were my 2 cents. =)

**EDIT1:** As Jeff pointed in his answer, even if the image links are replaced by the correct form (from `i.stack.` to `i.`), the problem still remains as the images will silently and gradually disappear from `imgur`. The `add button` feature is linked to a SE contract with the imagehost, which garantees that the images will be preserved from an eventual *spring cleaning*.

Comment: Nope, that can't work. Note that this is only about images that were not uploaded by means of the "add image" button. I'm afraid the system doesn't know how an image was uploaded. I just happen to know that Gonzalo hasn't used that button so far `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: oh I guess it can work! `=)` Gonzalo answered one of [my questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/creating-lists-of-figures-based-on-groups) and I saw the "code" of his answer. It seems there's no distinction between uploaded and pasted images, because the full image link is available, so it can be checked against a regex. There's still hope! `=P`

Comment: @Paulo: Huh, I don't quite understand what you're writing. Isn't it the _problem_ that there's no distinction between uploaded and pasted images if you look at the "code"? Am I missing something important?

Comment: @Hendrik: oh sorry, sometimes I don't make myself clear. `=)`. I'm gonna try to explain: when you use the `add image` button, the script uploads the image to `imgur` and returns the image link. It's just a convenience, in fact you can mimic this by manually going to `imgur` website, upload your image there, grab the code and paste in the answer (it's what Gonzalo did/does). In the eyes of the StackOverflow parser, it's just an image link. `=)`

Comment: @Paulo: No, there's a crucial difference that I explain [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/the-image-you-are-requesting-does-not-exist-or-is-no-longer-available/1439#1439). Did you read that answer of mine?

Comment: @Hendrik: terribly sorry, I didn't read that. There's really a distinction. I'm gonna take a look on possible solutions. Damn,  my master procrastination plan failed. Back to sketches. `=P`

Comment: @Paulo: By bad, I guess. Maybe I should have pointed out in my question that that answer is a must-read.

Comment: @Paulo: thanks for your interest in this issue. I've decided to do a manual re-uploading of the images. It will take some time, as I'm only allowed to do 5 edits in a day.